# derivative of composition of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\theta$ and $\psi$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to compute
$$\nabla_{\psi} \log \left( e^{[\theta]_\times}e^{[\psi]_\times}\right)$$

Where $[v]_\times$ is the skew-symmetric cross-product matrix $[v]_\times w = v\times w.$

If rotations commuted I would just get $\nabla_\psi (\theta+\psi) = I$, but, of course, they don't. Is there still a nice formula for the derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the formula for the derivative of the exponential map in [this paper](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/52144/DerivativeOfRotation.pdf?sequence=1) and the chain rule, I get that

$$\nabla_\psi \log\left(e^{[\theta]_\times}e^{[\psi]_\times}\right) = T\left(\log\left(e^{[\theta]_\times}e^{[\psi]_\times}\right)\right)^{-1}T(\psi),$$
where the matrix $T(v)$ is given by
$$T(v) = \begin{cases}I, & v = 0\\ \frac{vv^T+\left(e^{-[v]_\times}-I\right)[v]_\times}{\|v\|^2}, & v \neq 0\end{cases}$$
which is tractable for computation, if unpleasant.